Effect of movement of container on pressure of gas
Take a case- We have two containers A and B, one of the containers is moving with constant velocity while the other one is stationary. Both containers are identical, have same gas, same number of moles of gas too. Now, will there be pressure difference between the two containers? I know it's zero, but can't comprehend it. Can somebody please explain.
Also, take another case in which the container, instead of moving with constant velocity, is moving with constant acceleration. In that case, what will be the relation between the pressures observed in the two containers?

For an observer moving with the velocity of your moving container, he would consider your fixed container moving and his container not moving.  The pressure in container cannot depend on the frame of reference of the observer.

Ohk. Now, I got it. Thanks.

In case of constant acceleration the pressure in the moving container is not uniform it is increasing  to the rear like the pressure increasing in the air of earth.

In figure below, first case is a fluid container moving with constant horizontal speed. The second case is where the container has some non-zero acceleration in the horizontal direction.

Consider an imaginary cylindrical volume of the fluid within the container as shown in figure.

$A$ - area of circular cross section of cylinder
$l$ - length of cylinder
$P_1$ - Fluid pressure on the left side of cylinder
$P_2$ - Fluid pressure on the right side of cylinder
$m$ - mass of fluid within cylindrical volume
$a$ - acceleration of the container

Since there's no net fluid movement with respect to container (after stable state has been obtained), forces across each of these tiny volumes has to be balanced out in the container's frame of reference.
Case 1 - Container with constant speed: Pressure on each end of the container exerts a horizontal (inwards) force.
$$P_1 A=P_2 A \\ P_1=P_2$$
Hence, there's no pressure difference created due to the uniform speed of container. Since we didn't assume any particular speed value in the scenario or the end result. This must be true for all constant speed cases (even when $v = 0$). That is, pressure remains same irrespective of the "constant" speed of the container.
Case 2 - Container with acceleration: There's an additional pseudo-force ($ma$) acting on the volume, when forces are computed with respect to the container.
$$P_1A=P_2A+ma \\ (P_1-P_2)A=V\rho a=(Al)\rho a \\ P_1-P_2=l\rho a$$
Hence proved. A pressure gradient is created in a fluid due to the acceleration of the vessel and the gradient is such that there's higher pressure on the end away from the direction of acceleration.

All is good, except that fluid column length $\ell$ in the drawing must be extended to the right wall of container, since it all affects $P_1$ pressure. (By analogy, as per water pressure in the ocean $\rho g h~~\to$, $h$ also means depth below sea surface level. So here $l$ must be also until container right wall, or more exactly until water ends in the right side if container is not full.)

@vincent I disagree. The proof attempted above stands for the "pressure difference" across any two points on a horizontal line within fluid. As you hinted, this proof certainly can be extended to any two points within the fluid. If we choose these points along a vertical line, then all vertical forces have to be considered; which would include weight of the fluid column. But nevertheless, since the quantity in LHS is pressure difference (not absolute pressure) between 2 points, RHS should contain distance between those points (not the distance from an extreme end)

@DarkMIR4GE I think you're replying to the wrong user.

You're right. Apologies. @agnius please consider my comment above as reply to you.

Yes, pressure difference does not depend on whole column, just on volume between those points. I was somewhat concentrated on calculating total pressure on $P_1$ , but sure you can get it by adding $P_2$ to the $l\rho a$. Apologies.


Now, will there be pressure difference between the two containers? I
know it's zero, but can't comprehend it. Can somebody please explain.

If the motion is in a straight line as well as constant speed, then both containers are in inertial (non accelerating) reference frames. Then, according to the Principle of Relativity, which says the laws of physics apply equally in all inertial frames, there should be no difference in the properties (including pressure) of the gases between the two containers due only to their relative velocities.
Hope this helps.

EDIT: Judging by the low number of upvotes, I guess not many people are convinced by the logical argument I presented earlier, so I have decided to present a case based on calculations instead:

Calculation: Pressure is force per unit area (F/A
). Using the definition of force in terms of momentum we can write the equation for pressure as:
$$ P = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t \cdot A} = \frac{m \Delta v}{A \Delta t} $$
Considering just the right hand wall of the vessel with area A and with velocity to the right defined as positive, the pressure on the right hand wall of the vessel when stationary is:
$$ P = \frac{N m \Delta v}{A \Delta t} = \frac{N m (v_0 - v_1)}{A \Delta t} $$
where N is the number of particles that collide with the wall in a given time interval, $v_0$ is the velocity of a given particle before it impacts the wall and $v_1$ is the velocity of the particle after the collision. Assuming elastic collisions, the velocity after the impact is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the velocity before the collision, so $v_1=−v_0$ and the above equation can be written as:
$$ P = \frac{N m (v_0 - v_1)}{A \Delta t} = \frac{N m (v_0 + v_0)}{A \Delta t} = \frac{N m (2 v_0)}{A \Delta t} \tag{1}$$
Now if we consider the situation when the vessel is moving with constant velocity u to the right, the calculation becomes:
$$ P = \frac{N m ((v_0 + u) - (v_1 + u))}{A \Delta t} = \frac{N m (v_0 + u + v_0 - u)}{A \Delta t} = \frac{N m (2 v_0)}{A \Delta t}, $$
which is the same as equation (1) so the motion of the vessel has had no effect on the pressure on the right hand wall. All the same applies to any other wall of the vessel, so we can conclude that relative motion of a vessel containing a gas under pressure has no effect on the pressure in the vessel in any reference frame. In other words, gas pressure can be considered an invariant.
which is the same as equation (1) so the motion of the vessel has had no effect on the pressure on the right hand wall. All the same applies to any other wall of the vessel, so we can conclude that relative motion of a vessel containing a gas under pressure has no effect on the pressure in the vessel in any reference frame. In other words, gas pressure can be considered an invariant.

Logical argument: Imagine the two equal containers have flat sides that slide alongside each other. Each container has a hole in its sliding side that is sealed by the surface of the other container most of the time. When the holes coincide, gas can move from one container to the other if there is a pressure difference between the two containers. Which way does the gas move?
POV 1) If in frame A, we say container A is stationary and container B is moving and has greater pressure due to its movement, we would have a net flow from container B to container A, and we would expect to end up with more gas molecules in container A.
POV 2) In frame B, the observer considers container B to be stationary and container A to be moving. If movement causes the pressure to increase, in this reference frame, we would expect a net gas flow from A to B and to end up with more gas molecules in container B.
These two points of view contradict each other and obviously cannot happen at the same time. Both containers cannot end up with more gas molecules than the other. That is a physical impossibility. If the movement of a container causes the pressure to change, we end up with a contradiction, so the logical conclusion is that the pressure does not change with relative velocity.

Relativistic calculation: A naïve analysis of the situation in Special Relativity would suggest the moving container should length contract and so the pressure in the moving container should increase, but that is not the correct conclusion.
In SR the Lorentz transformations of force are:
$F'_{\parallel} = F$ and
$F'_{\perp} = F\gamma^{-1}$
The Lorentz transformations of area are:
$A'_{\parallel} = A$ and
$A'_{\perp} = A\gamma^{-1}$
where the $\parallel$ and $\perp$ subscripts indicate parallel and perpendicular measurements respectively and the unprimed quantities are the proper measurements when the vessel is at rest with respect to the observer.  It follows that the pressures measured when the vessel is moving relative to the observer are:
$$P'_{\parallel} = \frac{F'_{\parallel}}{A'_{\parallel}} = \frac{F}{A} = P$$ and
$$P'_{\perp} = \frac{F'_{\perp}}{A'_{\perp}} = \frac{F\gamma^{-1}}{A_{\perp}\gamma^{-1}}  = \frac{F}{A} = P$$
so it turns out even in Special Relativity, the relative motion has no effect on the pressure on the walls of the container in any direction.
We could do more involved calculations involving the Lorentz transformation of momentum and relativistic velocity addition etc. but we still end up with the same result. Gas pressure is invariant.


Also, take another case in which the container, instead of moving with
constant velocity, is moving with constant acceleration. In that case,
what will be the relation between the pressures observed in the two
containers?

In this case, we end up with a pressure and density gradient in the accelerating container, while the pressure and density in the stationary container remain uniform. Unlike the purely relative inertial case, we can always tell the difference between a frame with acceleration and an inertial frame.
